# ArcGIS Reclassify fails in Python Toolbox

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, python-toolbox, arcgis-10.6, error-000864

I'm trying to build a Python Toolbox to analyze submarine landslides. Among other things I want to run the aspect tool and then reclassify the aspects into groups with a 45 degree interval. Therfore I do the following:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.sa
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\FIP_Tools20191118\GIS_files\SBP_Toolbox.gdb'

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
        
aspect_ras = arcpy.sa.Aspect('Smooth_Bathymetry', 'PLANAR', 'METER')
aspect_ras.save('aspect_raster')

remap = RemapRange([[0, 45, 45], [45, 90, 90], [90, 135, 135], [135, 180, 180], [180, 225, 225], [225, 270, 270], [270, 315, 315], [315, 360, 360]])
reclass_ras = arcpy.sa.Reclassify('aspect_raster', 'Value', remap, 'NODATA')
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(reclass_ras, 'reclass_Ras')
```

The weird thing is that the above code works fine as long as I run it from Pycharm or the ArcGIS Python window, but when I try to put it into a python toolbox (.pyt) and run it, it throws the following errors:

> ERROR 000864: Reclassification: The input is not within the defined domain.

> ERROR 000893: An empty GP value or text is entered.

I really don't understand why it won't work in a toolbox. The fact that it works otherwise tells my that there isn't a fundamental problem within my code, which is why I'm expecting it to be some background stuff that I'm missing. I'm really at a loss here.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6.1 on Windows 10

Comment: This is not a Python Toolbox (`.pyt`) formatted file. It appears to be a script tool, but with all parameters hard-coded.

Comment: actually, you're right. It's a bigger project, so what I do is I have some custom modules and functions that are called in the Python Toolbox. This code is what is called in the python toolbox when it throws the error. I can provide additional code if needed.

Comment: you're right. 'aspect_raster' is what I meant. I edited it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, actually I just fixed it now. To answer my question, I need to provide a bit of additional background:

Basically, the aspect interval isn't hard coded, it's supplied through a parameter. However, it was accessed through the .ValueAsText method, which returns the value as a string. However, afterwards it is treated as an integer, which is where the errors come from. For sure also why it worked fine in PyCharm but not as a .pyt.
See the mwe below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "ShearBandPropagation"
        self.alias = "Shear Band Propagation"

    # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
    self.tools = [CreateGeometry]
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName='Workspace',
        name='workspace',
        datatype='DEWorkspace',
        parameterType='Required',
        direction='Input')

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName='Smooth Bathymetry',
        name='smooth_bathymetry',
        datatype='Raster Layer',
        parameterType='Required',
        direction='Input')

    param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName='Aspect Interval',
        name='aspect_interval',
        datatype='GPLong',
        parameterType='Required',
        direction='Input')

    param2.value = 45
    param2.filter.type = "Range"
    param2.filter.list = [1, 360]

    param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName='Output',
        name='output_name',
        datatype='Raster Layer',
        parameterType='Required',
        direction='Output')


    params = [param0, param1, param2, param3]
    return params

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""

    workspace = parameters[0].valueAsText
    smooth_bathymetry = parameters[1].valueAsText
    aspect_interval = parameters[2].valueAsText
    output = parameters[3].ValueAsText

aspect_ras = arcpy.sa.Aspect(smooth_bathymetry, 'PLANAR', 'METER')
aspect_ras.save('aspect_raster')

reclassified_list = [] # create values for remap range based on input parameter
# here is where it went wrong: the correct thing to do would have been: aspect_range = int(aspect_interval)
aspect_range = aspect_interval
while aspect_range <= 360:
    if aspect_range % 1 != 0:
        reclassified_list.append([aspect_range - aspect_interval, aspect_range, int(aspect_range*10)])
        aspect_range += aspect_interval
    else:
        reclassified_list.append([aspect_range - aspect_interval, aspect_range, int(aspect_range)])
        aspect_range += aspect_interval

reclass_ras = arcpy.sa.Reclassify('aspect_raster', 'Value', RemapRange(reclassified_list), 'NODATA')
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(reclass_ras, output)
```